# Cannot add or edit current pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I keep getting this page whenever I try to edit or add a new page. I cannot do anything to edit my Wordpress pages. My website currently uses WordPress 5.3.2 and it also uses the new Avada theme 6.2. It has been like this all day. [What I see when I click to edit through fusion builder or the regular wordpress editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVT9G.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that there is an issue with CSS files delivery, it looks like the styles files (css files) are not being opened on your website page.

Possible reasons that might cause this are:

1. 404 error: means all .css files are being called from the wrong URL which might happen if you changed your website URL recently.
2. You might have moved your website to SSL which changes the http:// to https://.

Possible solutions:

1. Try to clean your website cache.
2. Try to access your website using the private session within your browser.

Can you please share your website url?

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will try that out. Edit - I emptied my cache and it has not worked.

Comment: I have tried using a private session and that does not work as well.

Comment: I just checked your website front page and the Admin login page, and both are looking fine to me, there are no CSS issues on my end. This is usually a sign of caching issue, unless if the editing admin page on your WP backend is triggering issue wit styles. Can you please try out:
Go to the page where you facing this issue and hold " Ctrl+Shift+i " then on the top right corner check of you have any errors, warning, or message about your page. You should find little icons with a red cross when you click on it you will see more info on the bottom in the "Consol" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the browser console to see what error is occurring.
In the recent version of Wordpress this is causing performance errors at its core:

Try adding the line below to your wp.config file below that IF:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

I had an error that did not load JQuery, when clicking on any button to upload files not working. So after I added the last line it worked.